# can not display the the relational value in index in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I am trying to display all the members for each school, but getting only empty arrays. Do you have any idea how to display all the values?

```
<% @schools.each do |school| %>
 <%= school.name %>
<%= school.members.each do |member| %>
 <%= member.name %>
 <%= member.email %>
<% end %>
```

I get this result instead of the name of all the members of each school:

```
Westminster [] UCL [] City []
```

Comment: It is impossible to say anything unless you have your model shown.

Comment: its many to many relationship with a members_school model. School has name, members has name and email and foreign key school_id

Comment: Well, this code should work, it’s fine. You likely experience problems with your data.

Comment: I am displaying a form on the member side, where you are able to enter the member name, member email and choose a school from the list. However when I submit, does not display here, when I want to present all the members belongs to the school

Comment: I agree with @mudascobwa, there is some issue with your data.  Meaning in your said form, as you are describing, there is likely as issue there on create where the join table or school/member not being created properly.  I would start there and watch the params that are sent, if any are rejected, putting a binding in the create action/etc to track it down.  else paste some controller/form code here.

Comment: We need some more info tho help you. You only display an `.erb` file without sufficient context. Do you try to output a simple text file or do you expect this to generate an `HTML`-table? How many members do your `Model` schools have? What character is the square you might have copied? (Or are they even indicating an empty array?)

Comment: The empty square brackets would indicate that some array is empty. However it is somewhat unclear how the `.erb` code might have printed that. You should look at your model objects in `irb` and provide us with some more info on their contents.

Comment: Just to clean up your output remove the equals in `<%= school.members.each do |member| %>` so it becomes `<% school.members.each do |member| %>`

Comment: Good point @SteveTurczyn, that is the reason for the empty brackets. `.each` is going to return the whole array which seems to be empty and is then output due to `<%=`. That indicates rather clearly, that the `members` method returns an empty set, but in order to verify that we would have to get some info on how `@schools` is retrieved (from a database I would guess).